# Visual Studio Missing stuff in Tools Options

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So I started using VS 2013 over a year ago now, but I never noticed I was missing options until I tried to use TypeScript and set the "Automatically compile ..." to true.

The only (Tools -> options -> text) Editor items I have are (General, JavaScript, CSS Advanced, HTML). (See Pic)

[image: Tools -> Options]

I am also missing a lot of other things in Options that everyone else seems to have.

I thought maybe I just didn't include stuff when I installed, but when I go to add optional features through (Add Remove Programs -> Modify) everything is checked except "Blend for Visual Studio". (See Pics)

I can't find anything on the web relating to my problem.  Can anyone give me some direction.

[image: Installed VS Features]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do see a "Show all settings" checkbox at the bottom, did you try checking this?

Comment: Thanks, it is always the little things that get ya.

Comment: If it worked I'm glad I could help. *stop* *stare*.... hmmmm.... checkbox? *suspecting glare*

Answer (score -1):

I don't personally use visual studio but I know there are differences between version offerings. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx

Have you checked which versions those with these options are using?